# How do I use sudo (or a sudo replacement) without ubuntu on windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, sudo

I am trying to use install these libraries:

```
git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
cd pyaudio
sudo python setup.py install
sudo apt-get installl libportaudio-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev
sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition
```

But I do not have Ubuntu, runas doesn't work either I just get the help thing for runas, I can run the runas examples though, I was able to clone the `pyaudio` thing, and I was obviously able to use `cd pyaudio`, but for the `setup.py`, I removed `sudo`, and it did something, so I'm just hoping that was the right something, but for the rest it doesn't work. Also, if I do have to install Ubuntu and dual-boot it, does it share files with windows? (Please keep in mind I am very new to programming, so I would appreciate it if you could keep your terms simple)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can install Ubuntu using VMWare Workstation Player and indeed share files with windows. It requires some configuration that I don't know by heart, but I've used it regularly. Always had to look it up, though. I've used this with Ubuntu 14, but I think you should try Ubuntu 18, since it has a lot of improvements. (Note that this is NOT dual boot!)

Comment: Ubuntu and Windows are different operating systems.  Thus, they have different command languages.  I suggest that you solve more than just the local problem by looking up Windows commands in general, starting with "Install Python on Windows".  This will solve *many* more tasks for you than a single SO question.

Comment: `apt-get` and these package names is specific to the Ubuntu/Debian-based packaging system and make no sense at all outside of it. The lack of `sudo` is literally the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. To execute commands as an admin: Right click the shortcut to cmd.exe, and select 'Run as administrator'.
2. There's no git unless you install [gitbash](https://gitforwindows.org/) or something similar
3. There's no apt-get in Windows. Get the installers for [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), and [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows#12476379) online, and install them. (pip is included with the later python versions)
4. Use pip to fetch what else you need.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to run a console as an administrator and type all commands without word "sudo". Also there is Chocolatey package manager for Windows which works the same as "apt-get" for Linux. However, all packages that you want to install are avaliable only for Linux.

Comment: No not "the Ubuntu package manager"... If you said Debian it would be more accurate. **All** distros based on Debian, that use apt, and .deb packages. Ubuntu is only one of the many distros based on Debian.